# Share a threadpool between two classes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a threadpool of a fixed size 12. Now I have two classes that implement Runnable and 20 objects of each class. I can submit all the tasks and the threadpool will do its job as regular.

What I would like to do is to make a delimiter. So, in case that I submit this 40 tasks, the thread pool will not process more than 6 of each class concurrently. So the thread pool will behabe like 2 smaller thread pool of size 6. Is it possible by the API of java or guava?

Comment: Would it be an option to create two pools of size 6?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think you're trying to find out how many active threads there are in a threadpool and then delimit them, try [`ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29)

Comment: @px06 What have you won if you know the active count in respect to the requirements stated in the question?

Comment: So you want to have the functionality of 2 thread pools, but using only one? Why? How did you come up with this seemingly very random requirement?

Comment: Everything that I am asking is because of requirements of the project. I know that I can use 2 pools, or another technique. Bu the requirements are what I just asked, and not other.

Comment: I thought you're asking FIFO/FAIR scheduling when sharing a pool. So disappointed.

Comment: @DanielOchoa It's just that when inexperienced programmers follow given instructions blindly, they can do very stupid things. When you explain things well, you can be given the most optimal solution rather than just what you think is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without questioning the "why" - it can be achieved using semaphores, each of them created with the count of 6, each of them delimiting the number of tasks of each type to exactly 6 at the same time.

Here is a basic working sample:

```
public class TaskDelimitingTest {

  private enum Tasks {TASK1, TASK2};

  private static ConcurrentHashMap<Tasks, AtomicInteger> taskObserver = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public static class Task implements Runnable {

    private static final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(6, true);
    private final Tasks task;

    public Task(Tasks task) {
      this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        taskObserver.get(task).incrementAndGet();
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        taskObserver.get(task).decrementAndGet();
        sem.release();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public void postToExecution(ExecutorService executor) {
      try {
        sem.acquire();
        executor.execute(this);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Task1 extends Task {

    public Task1() {
      super(Tasks.TASK1);
    }

  }

  public static class Task2 extends Task {

    public Task2() {
      super(Tasks.TASK2);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
      taskObserver.put(Tasks.TASK1, new AtomicInteger());
      IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(i -> {
        new Task1().postToExecution(executor);
        System.out.println(taskObserver);
      });
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
      taskObserver.put(Tasks.TASK2, new AtomicInteger());
      IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(i -> {
        new Task2().postToExecution(executor);
        System.out.println(taskObserver);
      });
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }

}
```

In this example I create 100 tasks of each of the two types in two separate threads, so that they can compete with each other, I also put a `Thread.sleep` in the `run` method so that they simulate different execution time.

The output of this programm is - In the "warmup" phase

```
    {TASK2=1, TASK1=1}
    ...
    {TASK2=2, TASK1=3}
    ...
    {TASK2=4, TASK1=3}
    ...
    {TASK2=4, TASK1=4}
    ...
    {TASK2=4, TASK1=5}
    ...
```

at some time the pool gets saturated and then it goes only like that:

```
    {TASK2=6, TASK1=6}
    ...
```

So only at maximum 6 threads of each type are being executed simultanously.